# Msbuild with specific version

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I am using teamcity for creating nuget packages that are being feed to a octopus deploy server. I ran into a problem regarding the dll versions that are installed as a nuget dependency, more precisely they are updated to the latest version instead of the specified version, even though in csproj, it checked the option specific version.

I don't know where it is the problem, on the local machine the build does not upgrade the dll, only on teamcity.

Is it msbuild related, or some set up to the nuget installer step, when I restore the nuget package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say you have the wrong options in the nuget installer step. There is an option there which allows you to enable/disable automatic updating.

Comment: The option for update nuget packages is not checked, what is more weird is that in msbuild I have substep to say so, that gives a warning about the fact, that I am using an older library instead of a latest one and recommends me either fix in visual studio, either in app.config runtime bindings. However, those library have specific version set to true, so I don't know, where it is the problem, my first suspect is still msbuild.

Comment: I solved it by making a clean build every time, when I trigger a teamcity build.